# Breakpoints don't work when running dev_appserver.py in local PyCharm

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm, dev-appserver

I'm building web application the following technologies.

```
PyCharm(2019.02)
Python(2.7)
Django
Google App Engine(for local development, I use dev_appserver.py)
```

And I would like to put breakpoints on my code on PyCharm to debug the application, however, they don't work.

**How they don't work**

1. They don't stop the process when I access the web application.
2. PyCharm doesn't show me breakpoints mark on debug console. I share the screenshot.

https://gyazo.com/17a0a3e7c9e25473bf862c488289b648

Correctly, PyCharm should show me it like the following link.

https://gyazo.com/b621a748c8f0fe7977852252c871f74f

How can I debug Google App Engine application for my local using breakpoints?

---

I push the 'Run' button, so there is no breakpoint mark on the console and breakpoints don't work.

Comment: looks like you are not running in debug mode

Comment: @daltonfury42 Oh, you're right... I'm sorry... Now I realized what I did...